# Is a circular dependency acceptable when a type declaration file imports an enum from implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enums, circular-dependency

Say I have an implementation file `module.ts` and a type declaration file `module.d.ts`.

```js
// module.ts
import type ConfigI from 'module.d.ts';

export enum ConfigType {
  Simple,
  Complex
}

function performTask(config: ConfigI) {
  if (config.type === ConfigType.Simple)
    // ...
}
```

```js
// module.d.ts
import ConfigType from 'module.ts';

export interface ConfigI {
  type: ConfigType;
}
```

Typescript does not permit enums in declaration files because they contain runtime values. How could I go about restructuring this to get rid of the circular dependency?

A potential solution is declaring ConfigType like:

```js
// module.d.ts
export type ConfigType = 
  0 | // Simple
  1;  // Complex
// ...
```

however, that makes it a bit more difficult depending on if you want the type of the enum to be a number or a string. `config.type === ConfigType.Simple` is definitely more readable than `config.type === 0`; You could make `ConfigType` a string type, which is more readable, but then it loses the numeric value.

Comment: Yes, type-level circular dependencies are not an issue. You can emphasise that by using `import type { ConfigType } from 'module.ts';`

Comment: Why do you even use a separate type declaration file when you're writing TypeScript code anyway?

Comment: @Bergi I wanted to separate type definitions and implementation. I want to prevent polluting the code with typescript definitions by moving them to a separate file.

Comment: If you want to have a public interface and a private implementation, put them in different modules (with different names, not just different file extensions), and put the enum in the interface. Otherwise, keeping the types of the implementation in the same file is not "pollution" but improves readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ConfigType` is not a circular structure, so a simple solution is place that in it's own module. But of course that will require another import from the consumer.

But a better option IMO, is don't use enums.  There not a standard Javascript concept, and Typescript nowadays try's to strictly adhere to ES specs.

Another idea is to use Typescript typesystem to make sure you get the correct values.  You can use `keyof` to then get the string names, and then for the values you can use the array accessor format `Type[name]`

```
type ConfigType = {
  Simple: 0,
  Complex: 1
}

const a:keyof ConfigType = 'Complex';

const b:ConfigType['Complex'] = 1;

const c:ConfigType['Simple'] = 1; //this errors as it should be 0
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAVc0C8UDeAUFFAMooC2YANhAFxQAMANMbHFbQB4MCMhAX0KEAxogDOwKAEM6Aawgg4SdsnRZIUPAHJ4nCF20BuYWISSoAIzrw1mbAG1dHGge0BdLVF4nREqSI2iKj2kE7k%20h5ePlAA9LHAABYo4lAQAE7pcOmp0qkoUuKJcACu1AAmVtCMhEA)

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much came to a similar conclusion and replaced enums with string union types. This solution will come in handy, though.